# 21.5" iMac Mid 2010 | Restarting On Boot OSX Utilities Menu

Tags: imac, startup, restart

I made an OSX High Sierra Bootable USB. The iMac starts fine and enters the MacOS Utilities GUI screen. But when I press either Disk Utility or Install MacOS, the iMac restarts ubrubtly.

What could be the reason?

[image]

Comment: How did you create the bootable USB ?

Comment: @375914 Here are [instructions](https://support.apple.com/HT201372)